# Python3 How to implement sliding window counts on Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a plot from a large Pandas dataframe. The data is in the following format

```
Type     Number    ...unimportant additional columns

Foo       13  ...
Foo       25  ...
Foo       56  ...
Foo       56  ...
Bar       10  ...
Bar       10  ...
Bar       11  ...
Bar       23  ...
```

I need to count the number of elements from column 'Number' in a sliding window from x to x+i to determine the number of values falling in each sliding window bucket.

For example, if the window size is i=10, starting at x=0, and incrementing x by 1 each step, the sliding window bucket for 'Foo' a correct result for the above example would be:

```
      Foo    Bar

  0    0      2    #(0-10)
  1    0      3    #(1-11)
  2    0      3    #(2-12)
  3    1      3    #(3-13)
  4    1      3    #(4-14)
   .
   .
   .
  20   1      1    #(13-23)
  21   0      1    #(14-24)
  22   1      1    #(15-25)
   . 
   .
   .
```

The answer would have df.max().max - [Window Length] rows, and len(df.columns) columns.

Toy code to generate a similar dataframe might be the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

str_arr = ['Foo','Bar','Python','PleaseHelp']
data1 = np.matrix(np.random.choice(str_arr, 100, p=[0.5, 0.1, 0.1, 0.3])).T
data2 = np.random.randint(100, size=(100,1))
merge = np.concatenate((data1,data2), axis=1)

df = pd.DataFrame(merge, index=range(100), columns=['Type','Number'])
df.sort_values(['Type','Number'], ascending=[True,True], inplace=True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

How can I generate such a list efficiently?

Edit Note: Thanks to FLab who answered my question earlier before I clarified my question.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you didn't formulate your code as a humongous one-liner with `np.concatenate` etc.  Break it down into steps and make it clear.

Comment: Okay thanks for the advice. Let me know if it would be better to break it down further.

Comment: You probably want to reset index after sorting?

Comment: Yes, I should. I will figure out how to do that.

Comment: simply add .reset_index(drop = True) at the end of the line

Comment: I did it slightly differently to improve clarity, to also address John Zwinck's appropriate suggestion

Comment: Also, why do you have 1000 (thousand) Numbers but only 100 (hundred) type strings?

Comment: Sorry FLab, I didn't catch that mistake. Corrected now

Comment: what do you mean by "df.max(axis=0) rows"? df.max(axis=0) gives you the maximum of each column.

Comment: JaminSore, I fixed this. Sorry I am not great with python, so I am making mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my proposed solution.

For convenience, let's force 'Number' column to be an int.

```
df['Number'] = df['Number'].astype(int)
```

Define all possible ranges:

```
len_wdw = 10
all_ranges = [(i, i+len_wdw) for i in range(df['Number'].max()-len_wdw)]
```

And now check how many observations there are for "Number" in each of this ranges:

```
def get_mask(df, rg):
    #rg is a range, e.g. (10-20)
    return (df['Number'] >= rg[0]) & (df['Number'] <= rg[1])

result = pd.concat({ rg[0] : 
                        df[get_mask(df, rg)].groupby('Type').count()['Number']
                   for rg in all_ranges},
                 axis = 1).fillna(0).T
```

For the randomly generated numbers, this gives:

```
    Bar   Foo  PleaseHelp  Python
0   1.0   4.0         3.0     1.0
1   1.0   5.0         2.0     1.0
2   1.0   5.0         3.0     1.0
3   1.0   4.0         3.0     0.0
4   1.0   3.0         3.0     1.0
.....
85  2.0   3.0         4.0     1.0
86  1.0   3.0         3.0     1.0
87  1.0   4.0         3.0     1.0
88  1.0   4.0         4.0     1.0
89  1.0   3.0         5.0     1.0
```

Comment: I marked it as accepted, and upvoted. My reputation is too low for the upvote to show up. Thanks!

Comment: FLab, after playing with the code you gave me, I realized this is almost what I wanted, but not exactly.  Can you edit your answer on the ranges line to: all_ranges = [(i,i+len_wdw) for i in range(df['Number'].max()-len_wdw]

Comment: Good spot, changed accordingly

Comment: FLab, thanks for all your help. This solution becomes increasingly computationally intensive as the maximum value in 'Number' becomes very large. One solution is to increase the window and step size. Another solution would be to implement a solution that iterates over the rows of the dataframe instead of iterating over the ranges object. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you are after. Are you sure you need overlapping ranges? Why not consider (1-10), (11-20) and so on?

Comment: Is there a more efficient solution that doesn't consider overlapping ranges? At the end, I need to turn this data into a histogram, and as long as explicitly state what the plot shows it likely won't make a difference